# Jpa (hibernate) return type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I use jpa (with Hibernate's implementation).

What is the best way to determine the return type of a query?
I want numbers to return by default as java.lang.Long (or oracle.jbo.number) - not as java.math.BigDecimal.

Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question. The return type of a query will surely be determined by the underlying HQL executed by the query.

Comment: +1, the result type will depend on the query you specify.  What are you selecting?  If its a function, those can be known based on which function.  If a property, the result type is the same as the property type.  But you really need to show us the query.  If you want to see the result type in a programatic way, org.hibernate.Query.getReturnTypes() will show you that (the results are Hibernate Type instances)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a long, why not just cast the result to a Number and use .longValue()  ????
I'm assuming here that you're getting back an Object (or an array of object).  If you're unsure of what type it will return for a tuple or projection, take advantage of the class hierarchy, since Long, Integer, Short, Double, Float, BigInteger and BigDecimal all extend the Number class.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your result with different types as you likes, see this

```
       long result= (Long)query.getSingleResult();
       or
       BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal)query.getSingleResult();
       or
       Object result = (Object)query.getSingleResult();
```